# Copy file from shared folder of server to local

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

Hi I am trying to copy a file in shared folder on a remote server but getting error access is denied, what kind of permission needs to be given to the file or folder?

```
File.Copy(psSourceFile, "\\\\" + psDestinationServer + psDestinationFile);
```

where psSourceFile="\server\folder\folder\filename

Comment: Check about Path.Combine to avoid manual concatenation and  ONLY for test, you can allow **write** for "everyone". If it's works, remove everyone and add the user that runs your application.

Answer (score 0):

I have given the permission on the shared folder for identity of application pool on which web application is running and it worked for me.